# Django : Post counts per user in user's list

Tags: django

How to return the user's posted items from another model , as example I have model called Post ( with Author as foreign key to User's Auth Model ) . how to return list of users and number of Posts for each ? may be latest post for everyone in a list .

```
def users_list(request):
    users = UserProfile.objects.all()
    for userposts in users:
        posts_count = Post.objects.filter(author=users.user).count()
    return render_to_response('users.html',{'users':users,'posts_count':posts_count})
```

Comment: see [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) in docs.

Answer (score 2):

Example usage of [annotate and Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```
for user in User.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('post')):
    print user.post_count
```

[Generating aggregates for each item in a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

> Per-object summaries can be generated using the annotate() clause. When an annotate() clause is specified, each object in the QuerySet will be annotated with the specified values

**Not** to be confused with [aggregate, Generating aggregates over a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset):

> What we need is a way to calculate summary values over the objects that belong to this QuerySet. This is done by appending an aggregate() clause onto the QuerySet

- annotate(): aggregate **per item** of the queryset
- aggregate(): aggregate all items of the queryset

Comment: Well it's working but it grabs all the counts of posts , by all users . :(

Comment: I think you used aggregate instead of annotate. Updated the answer with more example code. You can post your models maybe there is something special about then ?!

Answer (score 1):

```
UserProfile.objects.all().annotate(num_posts=Count('post'))
```